# How create a converter with Annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, metadata, data-annotations, java-6

I would like to create a anotation that converter from boolean to String. For example

```
public User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="active")
    //This the CustomAnnotation
    @ConvertMyBooleanToString
    private boolean isActive;
}
```

My Custom Annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
public @interface ConvertMyBooleanToString {
    //empty
}
```

Implementation somewhere

```
...
return valueFieldThatHasAnnotation ? "Yes" : "No";
...
```

So, I do not know how to implement this annotation so that every time before saving to the database, it does the conversion to a String.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you persisting to the database? If you are using hibernate, there is a built-in "yes_no" type

> yes_no: A type that maps an SQL CHAR(1) to a Java Boolean.

So something like:

```
@Type(type="yes_no")
public boolean isActive;
```

Comment: Thaank you Theo,

Comment: Why don't you accept the answer as correct ? I am trying to build my reputation here. :)